# Standard error of a ratio of differences of estimates

Tags: standard-deviation, standard-error, ratio

I am interested in calculating the standard error of a ratio of differences of estimates, like so:

$SE(\frac{X_2-X_1}{Y_2-Y_1})$

The s.e. of each difference is easy,

$SE(x_2-x_1)=\sqrt{SE(X_2)^2+SE(X_1)^2-(2\times cov(X_2,X_1))}$

But how can I compute the SE of the ratio of the differences?

Comment: I would start with the definition of variance: $Var(X) = E[(X - E[X])^2] = E[X^2] - (E[X])^2$ and the law of total variance. Are $X, Y$ independently distributed?

Comment: Also: https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/medstats/cRjKo_UUqiA

Comment: Actually I had come across that link. The end result is that, as long as certain assumptions are met, $var(X/Y) =  ((sX^2) + (sY^2)*(\mu  X^2)/(\mu Y^2))/(\mu Y^2)$. But that's if X and Y are sample means. What about if they're differences?

Comment: Note that you get into trouble if $Y_2 - Y_1$ is close to 0.

Comment: @EdM: That's correct. Not a concern in my particular case.

Comment: So presumably $Y_2 - Y_1$ is either always > 0 or < 0. Is that also true of $X_2 - X_1$? Could you work with log-transformed differences?

Comment: Yes that's true, but no, I need it expressed in differences of levels.

Comment: If $Y_2-Y_1$ has any appreciable chance (in your model) of being near $0$, then a standard error in the conventional sense intended here might not even exist, even though a second-order formula (as exemplified by the one in the question) would give a finite--and perhaps even small-value. Because this presents a serious risk of creating overconfidence in the results, you might want to consider alternative ways to express uncertainty about the estimates.

Comment: @whuber - interesting point. I don't suppose you might have a suggestion for alternative ways to express the uncertainty?

Comment: I don't have enough information to make a suggestion, Trevor.  I (or anyone else) would need to know--at a minimum--something about the nature and quantity of your data as well as your analytical objectives. If you care to share such information, then please do so by editing the post so that everyone will see it there.